# Pandas filling nan in between two numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

In a very large dataset I want to fill in nan values in between two values. The dataset looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                 'col2':[100,np.nan,100,np.nan,np.nan,999,999,np.nan,100,np.nan,np.nan,100]})
```

I want to only fill in those nan values that occur in between the 999 and 100. Expected output is:

```
df['col2'] = [100,np.nan,100,500,500,999,999,500,100,np.nan,np.nan,100]
```

Comment: If second `999` is changed to `NaN` how looks ouput?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If is possible test forward and backfilled missing values by `999` and `100` use:

```
s1 = df['col2'].ffill()
s2 = df['col2'].bfill()

df.loc[(s1.eq(999) & s2.eq(100)) | (s1.eq(100) & s2.eq(999)), 'col2'] = 500
print(df)
    col1   col2
0      1  100.0
1      2    NaN
2      3  100.0
3      4  500.0
4      5  500.0
5      6  999.0
6      7  999.0
7      8  500.0
8      9  100.0
9     10    NaN
10    11    NaN
11    12  100.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my problem. I am just curious is it possible to solve it using for loop? If so how? I know running loop is it recommended approach for large dataset. Just curious.